# How to remove duplicates from output with Python?

Tags: python, web-crawler

facing a issue here:

Following example:

```
for item in g_data:
        Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
        print(Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())
```

Output:

```
DMZ 3rd Tunnel - Korean Demilitarized Zone Day Tour from Seoul
Panmunjeom Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Private Tour
The Soul of Seoul - Small Group Tour
Seoul Helicopter Tour
Seoul City Full Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Tour
The Street Museum in the Urban Core - Small Group Tour
Korean Folk Village Day Tour
DMZ 3rd Tunnel - Korean Demilitarized Zone Day Tour from Seoul
Panmunjeom Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Private Tour
The Soul of Seoul - Small Group Tour
Seoul Helicopter Tour
Seoul City Full Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Tour
The Street Museum in the Urban Core - Small Group Tour
Korean Folk Village Day Tour
```

As you can see above, it gives me the output twice. Hence, only the second duplicates should be removed.

The result should look like:

```
DMZ 3rd Tunnel - Korean Demilitarized Zone Day Tour from Seoul
Panmunjeom Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Private Tour
The Soul of Seoul - Small Group Tour
Seoul Helicopter Tour
Seoul City Full Day Tour
Seoul City Half Day Tour
The Street Museum in the Urban Core - Small Group Tour
Korean Folk Village Day Tour
```

Can anyone provide me feedback how to delete the duplicates? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: What is `g_data`? What happens if you remove `print` assignment?

Comment: The type of `g_data` is not important to answer the question.

Comment: How big non duplicate lines may grow?

Answer (score 0):

You can use list or set (if order doesn't matter):

Using list:

```
result = []
for item in g_data:
    header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
    item = header[0].contents[0].text.strip()
    if item not in result:
        result.append(item)

print '\n'.join(result)
```

Using set:

```
result = set()
for item in g_data:
    header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
    result.add(header[0].contents[0].text.strip())

print '\n'.join(result)
```

Comment: thanks for your feedback. Both solutions are not working for me. Still getting the duplicates

Answer (score 0):

You should store the output in a set to verify if it has been "printed" already. After that you print out the elements of the set.

```
g_data = ["foo", "bar", "foo"]
g_unique = set()
for item in g_data:
        g_unique.add(item) # ensures the element will only be copied if not already in the set

for item in g_unique:
    print(item) # {'foo', 'bar'}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `set` to keep track of which items you have printed. This preserves the original order

```
already_printed = set()
for item in g_data:
    header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
    item = header[0].contents[0].text.strip()
    if item not in already_printed:
        print(item)
        already_printed.add(item)
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback but it is still not working:                                     g_data = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "itemsContent clearafter"})

        already_printed = set()
        for item in g_data:
            Header = item.find_all("div", {"class": "InnprodInfos"})
            item = (Header[0].contents[0].text.strip())
            if item not in already_printed:
                print(item)
                already_printed.add(item)                                                                           It still does not delete the dupicates. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple way to do this using list comprehension :)

```
s = set()
[s.add(text) for d_text in Header[0].contents[0].text.strip().split('\n')]
print('\n'.join([text for text in s]))
```

Comment: I will also use set() somehow to fix the issue